# Alinhamento de Caracteres

Tags: python, algoritmo, python-3.x

[image: alinhados]

Gostaria que alguém pudesse me dizer como faço para os números alinharem dessa forma com as palavras do índice superior, estou fazendo uma replica desse exemplo para um trabalho da faculdade, mas não consigo fazer com que os números se alinhem sem nunca expandir para fora da tela. Estou usando o pyhton 3.4.

Agradeço se puderem me ajudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) e ir adaptando a sua necessidade, veja um exemplo de uso baseado em alguns dados que você apresentou:

```
>>> from tabulate import tabulate
>>> data = [[2000, 0.00, 0.01, 0.00, 0.00, 1485, 2128, 79, 286], [4000, 0.01, 0.02, 0.00, 0.00, 2286, 4673, 264, 92]]
>>> headers = ['n', 'Insercao', 'Selecao', 'Merge', 'Quick', 'Insercao', 'Selecao', 'Merge', 'Quick']
>>> print(tabulate(data, headers, tablefmt='psql'))
+------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|    n |   Insercao |   Selecao |   Merge |   Quick |   Insercao |   Selecao |   Merge |   Quick |
|------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+---------|
| 2000 |       0    |      0.01 |       0 |       0 |       1485 |      2128 |      79 |     286 |
| 4000 |       0.01 |      0.02 |       0 |       0 |       2286 |      4673 |     264 |      92 |
+------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```